# How to increase the size of AWS EC2 block storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am a beginner of AWS.

I've created my Windows EC2 instance and now using it as Free tier.

The default storage size is 30GB.

And I've tried to increase this. Changed volumn size to 50 GB and on Windows system, I've also expanded the size to 50GB using Disk management too.

But the size is still 30GB and the alert for size limit to me.

How can I expand the size of AWS EC2 block storage correctly?

Please help me.. thanks.

Comment: Where are you seeing this as still 30GB?

Comment: Sounds to me that you did the AWS part correctly.  This becomes entirely a windows administration problem and should be asked at super user.

Comment: The size of storage is 50 GB now.. but the billing information shows that I have only now 30 GB and 100 % used.. also I am used over 103 % and I wonder I can pay extra money for these.

Comment: Please note that the AWS Free Tier is a billing discount, not a "free account". The Free Tier includes 30GB of Amazon EBS storage for a whole month. (Pro-rata, so instead you could use 60GB for half a month.) Since your volume is now over 30GB, if you use it for the full month you will be over the free tier. It is charged at 10c/GB/month, so you are effectively getting the first $3 for free and anything after that will be charged to your account. The Free Tier Dashboard will only show 30GB, because that is the limit of the "free" portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same by following these steps:

1. Create an Image/Snapshot of the current EC2 instance (FREE Tier)
2. Launch a new EC2 instance using that image AMI
3. Select the preferred disk size in disk selection step
4. Once the new instance is ready, you can associate the Old Elastic IP to new EC2 instance.
5. You are done with increasing the disk size.
6. You can then retire the old EC2 instance

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where are you seeing this size.
Steps are,

1. Increase size of EBS volume from console
   2.Once the volume is optimized(You can see this on EBS dashboard)
2. Stop/Start the machine and you will see the increase in size